# How to change a variable within a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I want to set up a dictionary with variable assigned to a key, and I want to have the key change when the variable does. I understand that when you assign a value to a dictionary, list, or variable, it keeps the value and not the exact code. How do I get around this? (This is Python 2, if you couldn't tell by the lack of parenthesis around the `print` function.)

I tried using the below code to change the key within the dictionary, and when that didn't work, I searched up how to solve this problem on google. Stack Overflow is my last resort.

```py
var = 7

dictionary = {
  "Var": var
}

var += 3

print var
print dictionary["Var"]
```

I want the output to be

```
10
10
```

but instead, it outputs

```
10
7
```

which means that `var` changed but `dictionary["Var"]` didn't.

Comment: sounds like a cheap veil around a mutable global. May i say that you shouldn't be doing this? pass the dictionary explicitly, mutate on the dictionary itself directly such as `dictionary["Var"] += 3`.

Comment: In this code, that may seem like the best option, but this is just an example. In my main code, this isn't really an option. I need a way to be able to change the variable and the key value at the same time.

Comment: if the main code is under your control, sounds like its time to refactor. You really shouldn't need to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have to use mutables, like:

```
var = [7]

dictionary = {
  "Var": var
}

var[0] += 3

print(dictionary)
{'Var': [10]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `int` in python is immutable.

```
var = 7
```

This creates new object `7`, and a new reference to this object `var`.

```
dictionary = {
  "Var": var
}
```

Here you are assigning to key `'Var'` same reference as var. So now `dictionary['Var']` and `var` points to the same object `7`.
Now when you write: `var += 3` it creates a new object `10` and assigns `var` to this object.

To omit it variable `var` should be some mutable object, or you should update dictionary value: `dictionary['Var'] += 3`

Comment: How can I create a mutable object for this situation? Edit: More specifically, what is a mutable object?

Comment: It is hard to explain in a few words. I recommend you to ask google. But here is a hint: lists are mutable. If you use: `var = [7]`, `dictionary['Var'] = var`, `var[0] += 3` and print dictionary, you will notice that value of `dictionary['Var']` has changed